# Manga where the hero's party is dead. The MC bring their dead corpses as zombie of some sort back to the town

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story (at least in the first few chapters I read) is about the adventure of the hero's party going back to the town after defeating the Demon King.

In the first few chapters it's shown as if the hero' party came back to their town after defeating the demon king. The went through snow, etc. Later we are shown that the hero' party is already dead and move as zombie of some sort. It's because they were already defeated and get killed by the demon king except the MC. The mc, is necromancer of some sort, then bring back their corpse to their home town. After that I haven't read any more chapter and forget to save. I just remember about this manga after watching some anime.

Comment: I'm confused. How did the main character not realise that his party of adventurers were dead? How did the necromancer get them back to town (and why?)

Comment: When in the past did you read this?

Comment: Also, telling us that you read it in the past isn't very helpful. Now if you'd read it in the future, that'd be amazing

Comment: @Valorum Definitely one of your wittiest comments in 2020 :-)

Comment: I am sorry if this is unclear, the mc is the necromancer and he bring back the dead party as zombie or some sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty certain this is the one-shot manga Yuusha Goikkou no Kaerimichi. ([MAL link](https://myanimelist.net/manga/114754/Yuusha_Goikkou_no_Kaerimichi), [A-P link](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/yuusha-goikkou-no-kaerimichi)) Note that the description on both of those pages is deliberately vague to preserve the twist.

Comment: I've skimmed it, certainly looks like a fit, +1. Though it'd be nice of you include some pictures of the key panels related to what the asker remembered